# JPanel with null layout in JScrollPane - don't see elements

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

I want to set every element location with `.setLocation(x, y)`

I need a `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`. But when I add components to `JPanel`, only buttons are showing. But not `JLabel`.

Method below is calling in `JFrame` constructor:

```
private void initGUI_test() {
    this.setSize(950, 700);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane mainScroll = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    JPanel container = new JPanel();

    mainScroll.setSize(900,500);
    mainScroll.setLocation(0,100);
    mainScroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    mainScroll.add(container);

    container.setLayout(null);
    container.setLocation(0, 0);
    container.setSize(900, 500);

    JLabel rowA = new JLabel();
    rowA.setSize(180, 26);
    rowA.setLocation(10, 100);
    rowA.setText("Row A");

    JButton loadButton = new JButton();
    loadButton.setSize(180, 34);
    loadButton.setLocation(290, 110);
    loadButton.setText("Load file");

    container.add(rowA);
    container.add(loadButton);

    this.getContentPane().add(mainScroll);
}
```

Comment: **DON'T** use a `null layout`! Swing was designed to work with different platforms, screen resolutions, pixel perfect GUI's are really hard to maintain, instead you should use a layout manager or [combinations of them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and empty borders for [space between components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874717/providing-white-space-in-a-swing-gui/17874718#17874718).

Comment: See [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more information about why you shouldn't use it. Once you've read the above links, please post a [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I agree completely with @Frakcool about `null layout`, the problem you are facing has a different source. You should not add components directly into `JScrollPane`, but into `JScrollPane`'s `ViewPort`.

The line `mainScroll.add(container);` should be `mainScroll.getViewport().add(container);`

Comment: Components are showing, thanks.
But scrolls don't work. Could You solve this problem yet, please?

Comment: This will be solved only after you give up this nonsense of using a `null` layout. The GUI is broken until then & anything you do to it is just a hack to hide the root problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok, so what do You think about Absolute layout? Is this wrong too?

Comment: *"..Absolute layout? Is this wrong too?"* ***Worse*** than a `null` layout in that (behind the scenes) it ***is a*** `null` layout, but it is pretending to be a layout manager that takes into account everything the typical layout managers take care of.

Comment: Ok, so I must learn any none intuitive layout based on borders:-( Giant calamity...
Thank You!